# How to achive this using viewpager2?

Tags: android

I'm designing a sample layout, where I have to design using `viewpager2` and achieved successfully up to a level but I need a slight modification to complete the final puzzle.

The design I want is

[sample design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdzxp.png)

In the end, I got this image like this in `viewpager2`

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDIMt.jpg)

activity_main.xml

```
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpageimageSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="285dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

slideAdapter.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/slideImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.plateofcarrot));
        sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.bread));
        sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.cucumber));
        sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.vegetables));
        sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.donuts));
        viewPager2.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(sliderItemBeans, viewPager2));

        viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);


        float pageMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.pageMargin);
        float pageOffset = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset);

        viewPager2.setPageTransformer((page, position) -> {
            float myOffset = position * -(2 * pageOffset + pageMargin);
            if (position < -1) {
                page.setTranslationX(-myOffset);
            } else if (position <= 1) {
                float scaleFactor = Math.max(0.7f, 1 - Math.abs(position - 0.14285715f));
                page.setTranslationX(myOffset);
                page.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
                page.setAlpha(scaleFactor);
            } else {
                page.setAlpha(0);
                page.setTranslationX(myOffset);
            }
        });
        viewPager2.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer);
        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                sliderHandler.removeCallbacks(sliderRunnable);
                sliderHandler.postDelayed(sliderRunnable, 3000);//slide duration
            }
        });
```

Please ask if anything needs in code 
Thank you

Comment: did you try to set width of slideImage?

Comment: @CôngHải If I do that  images  not going to be same in every device

Comment: I know but when you set it match_parent it will be stretch to full width. you have 2 options, 1. try wrap_content width, 2. fix width and set scale_type to center

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2) is android's official sample project for `ViewPager2` may be this could help you out.